# Can a managing editor replace the editor on a paper or remove them from the editorial board?

Tags: computer-science, editors, journal-workflow, management, responsibilities

Let's assume that a journal editor has been allocated a submission, started reviewing it himself, but stopped responding to the managing editor (= you) despite a long time since the authors had sent the submission (a little less than 3 years). The submission is longer than each of the papers accepted during the last 5 years, but historically, even longer papers were accepted. The authors were aware of the length issue, but they were concerned. The editor's Web page got updated (say, new teaching contents appears), so, he/she is  presumably still alive, but simply unresponsive.

Let's further assume that you've waited long enough (say, 1 month), tried to give them editor a call, but got no response at all.

Is it the managing editor's (= your) responsibility to replace the editor for the paper? And is it your task to get him/her off the editorial board?  What is the typical in the field of computer science?

Comment: I did flag it for reopening, right after I made my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a managing editor (which I'm using as a term synonymous to "editor-in-chief" etc - basically members of the editorial board with more responsibility) can replace the editor assigned to a paper or remove them from the editorial board.

Perhaps the more pertinent question is: **if the managing editor doesn't do it, who will?**

- The editor is not going to remove himself/herself from the editorial board - after all they're already inactive.
- The publisher is not likely to do anything without approval from the editorial board. In special circumstances they can, but doing so is a nuclear option that will leave a lot of bad feelings among the remaining editors and is therefore usually avoided.
- Obviously the authors and the peer reviewers can't do anything about it.

Therefore the managing editor must do it. Nobody else will.

Comment: There are sometimes other roles around: editorial assistant, associate managing editor (= associate editor-in-chief), advisory board, its chairperson.

Answer (score 2):

Journals have different models: Some appoint editors to terms of fixed length (say, 3 years per term, renewable at the end of the term), some others appoint them for indefinite periods. That will then also influence in what ways an editor can be removed.

In the former case, the more common case will simply be to not assign any papers to that person any more, then wait out the end of their term and just not reappoint them. In the latter case, one has to make difficult decisions that have the possibility to antagonize colleagues one has often known for many years and with whom one may in fact be friendly. It's definitely awkward to kick such a person off the board, or even to suggest that they resign voluntarily. I've had to do that and it's not fun. But there are situations where it's warranted because the person in question just can't seem to get their act together and turn papers around in a timely manner.

The easier case is definitely to take a paper from an editor and assign it to another. That's because it's not a public act: Very few people will know that it ever happened, and most of the time it's something that remains between the editor-in-chief and the editor in question. Both will know that it was necessary, but you're doing it in a way that it will never become public.

Both of these situations fall under the responsibility of the editor-in-chief. It's one of the responsibilities most people in this situation probably like the least about the job: Making technical decisions is easy, dealing with unpleasant situations that involve people you've known for a long time is hard. At the same time, it's clearly bad for the journal to let these situations linger, and so they need to be addressed sooner or later. Running away from it sounds easy but is, in the long run, also not going to endear you to the community around a journal.

Comment: *involve people you for a long time is hard* you accidentally a word

Comment: @AzorAhai -- thanks, I've corrected it. I mean "involve people you've known for a long time". I appreciate the pun of omitting a word in your comment :-)